# How to allow multiple column sizes depending on screen size?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a row that has 3 columns and depending on screen size I would like to be in the following form for xsmall(phones) screens:

```
[A-12]
[B-6][C-6]
```

and for the other sizes :

```
[A-4][B-4][C-4](all in one)
```

but instead I get 
xs:

```
[A-12]
[B-6(but it looks like 12?)]
[C-6(but it looks like 12?)]according to outline I drew
```

I followed the example that react-bootstrap has under [responsive grids](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/) but my actual code in inspect console look different.

My code in React app looks like the following:

```
<Jumbotron>
<Grid>
<Row>
<Col>
<!--Stuff goes here not important-->
</Col>
<Col>
<!--Stuff goes here not important similar to the row below-->
<Row>
<Col  md={4} sm={4} xs={12}>A</Col>
<Col  md={4} sm={4} xs={6}>B</Col>
<Col  md={4} sm={4} xs={6}>C</Col>
</Row>
<!--Stuff goes here not important similar to above-->
</Col>
</Row>
</Grid>
</Jumbotron>
```

Now the difference I see when inspecting my compiled code and react-bootstap is that their code does not have a :before and :after in their html inside each column. I dont know if I'm using bootstrap wrong or whats going on.I'm using react-bootstap 3 since when I tried to update to their beta npm just kept downloading bootstap 3 and not bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have the `6` anywhere, you have `12` instead:

Try this:

```
<Row>
  <Col  md={4} sm={4} xs={12}>A</Col>
  <Col  md={4} sm={4} xs={6}>B</Col>
  <Col  md={4} sm={4} xs={6}>C</Col>
</Row>
```

Each row will total 12, if it goes over 12, then you will get a new line. For A, B, and C, at `md` each of them is set to `4` which will mean they will fit in one row (4 + 4 + 4 === 12). For `xs` you have them all set to `12` which means each section will be on a new row. Instead you want to set A to `12` - this takes up the full row, and makes the next element start on the next row. Then you want B and C to be `xs={6}` and they will share the row (6 + 6 === 12).

Comment: Sorry those second 12s are actually 6 in my code. I made a mistake only here in stackoverflow when typing. Updated my question

Comment: How does it look with `xs={4}` on those rows, are they still full width?

Answer (score 0):

I'm now sure why but here is a work around I figured out.

```
<Row>
     <Col sm={4} xs={12}>
       <Row>
         <Col xs={12}>A</Col>
       </Row>
    </Col>
    <Col sm={8} xs={12}>
      <Row className="flex-nowrap">
         <Col xs={6}>B</Col>
         <Col xs={6}>C</Col>
       </Row>
    </Col>
</Row>
```